# Create a method with 2 integers as parameters

Tags: java, methods

I am practicing on methods and the question is:

> Create a method `getMax()` with 2 integers as parameters which returns the higher value

No problem here but the next part is a bit tricky for me:

> Create a Java program which reads 3 integers from the console and returns the highest of the 3 using the method `getMax()`

Here is what I have so far. I have a problem with that the method I create is using 2 variables but then in the main method I have to use it with 3 integers.
How come the method will calculate it since I've only assigned it with a 1 IF and 1 ELSE operation.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class zadacha2 {

    public static int getMax(int num1, int num2) {
        if (num1 > num2)
            return num1;
        else
            return num2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num1, num2, num3;
        System.out.println("Enther the num1, num2 and num3 variables");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        num1 = input.nextInt();
        num2 = input.nextInt();
        num3 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("the bigger value of the two is:" + getMax(num1, num2, num3));
    }
}
```

Comment: getMax(num1, getMax( num2, num3))

Comment: Maybe something like: `getMax(getMax(num1, num2), num3)`

Comment: Think about it.  If you had a bunch of numbers on paper, how would you pick the largest?

Comment: Can't you use `Math.max()`?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have declared `getMax()` as `public static int getMax(int num1, int num2)`, you can't pass three values to it. Therefore you will need to compare the first and second digit and then the higher one with the third one: `getMax(getMax(num1, num2), num3)`

Answer (score 1):

You can get max of 3 numbers with this method:

```
int max12 = getMax(num1, num2); // max of num1 and num2
int max = getMax(max12, num3); // get max from (max of 1 and 2) and num3
```

So you can write in a single line as:

```
int max = getMax(getMax(int num1, int num2), num3);
```

Here is the complete code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class zadacha2 {

    public static int getMax(int num1, int num2) {
        if (num1 > num2)
            return num1;
        else 
            return num2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num1, num2, num3;
        System.out.println("Enther the num1, num2 and num3 variables");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        num1 = input.nextInt();
        num2 = input.nextInt();
        num3 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("the bigger value of the two is:" + getMax(num1, getMax( num2, num3)));
    }

}
```